# How to enumerate multisets?

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

Given the eight-element set `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`, I would like to enumerate all multisets (subsets with repetition) of size `n`, where `n >= 3`.  For example, with `n = 3`, the sets `{1,1,1}, {1,1,2}, ..., {8,8,7}, {8,8,8}` would all be found.  Ideally, I would like to be able iterate through each set, rather than create one gigantic program-crashing list, so that I can use each set at the time it is found.  Since `Binomial[n, k]` only works for values of `k <= n`, I'm not sure how to best go about this.

Comment: Look at `Tuples[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 3]`.  Another interesting tip might be `Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 3]`.

Comment: @Artes: Tuples[] looks promising.  Subsets[] is no good, as it doesn't produce repetitions -- try Subsets[{1,2},3]

Comment: Actually you are looking for the [variations with repetition](http://users.telenet.be/vdmoortel/dirk/Maths/PermVarComb.html), for which the length of the result is always `n^k`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will generate all of them, just like `Tuples`. Not too hard to redo so as to get one at a time. Just use the correspondence between k-digit numbers base n (n=length of input set) and subsets length k allowing repetitions.

```
takeWithRepitions[set_, k_] := 
 Module[{n = Length[set], rule, vals}, 
  rule = Thread[(Range[n] - 1) -> set];
  vals = Map[IntegerDigits[#, n, k] &, Range[0, n^k - 1]];
  Map[# /. rule &, vals]]
```

Example:

```
takeWithRepitions[Range[5], 2]

(* Out[376]= {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2,
   3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 
  1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 
  4}, {5, 5}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your last sentence isn't yet clear to me, so I'll have to play with your code.

Comment: What I meant was that you can order these sets in a particular way. Say the full set has length n and your subsets have length k. You can order so that the rth one is given by the digits, base n, of r-1. Just remember to use leading zeros, and to have the correspondende 0-> first element, 1->second element, .... (If this is still not clear, I can add an edit to show explicitly.)

Comment: It's always nice to see an `IntegerDigits` solution!

Answer (score 3):

The "Multisets" package by David Bevan will generate a list of them,
(without the duplication that comes from using "Tuples" or the "takeWithRepitions" function described by Daniel Lichtbau).
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8115/

However, it does not appear to allow the iteration you want.